# How to pronounce Corlan Dashiva?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, pronunciation

Corlan Dashiva is an Asha'man at the Black Tower who is chosen to accompany Rand after the Battle of Dumai's Wells,

> and is in fact the name taken by Osan'gar, the reincarnated Aginor.

I could never work out how to pronounce the name Dashiva. The detailed glossaries at the end of each volume stopped just around the time he appeared, so we never got a pronunciation guide for his name. Is it Dah-SHEE-vah, Dah-SHY-vah, DAH-shih-vah, or something else?

Comment: He appears to not have answered this in an interview housed on theoryland

Comment: For what it's worth, the audiobook readers consistently pronounce it as "dah-SHEE-vah".

Comment: @DavidH Russian translators pronounce  it as "dah-SHEE-vah" too

Comment: That might be the best we get maybe someone can find what kind of input jordan had on the audiobooks, if he helped with pronunciation, listened to them,

Comment: @Himarm It probably wouldn't be too difficult to get an answer for this question by asking Brandon Sanderson directly through Reddit.

Comment: @DavidH dashiva was not a part of sandersons 3 books, so hes a bad source in this instance , jordans wife harriet and the editors are who wed need

Comment: @Himarm I realize that. However, the fastest way to get Harriet to answer a question is to get Brandon to ask her. ;)